# Python hangman game. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple Hangman game using Python. I have faced a problem which I can't solve and would be grateful to receive some tips from you guys.

Okay I will provide you with a sample of my code and below it, I will explain what my issue is:

```
# Here is my list of words
words = ['eight', 'nine', 'seven'...]
# Choosing a random word from the list
word = random.choice(words)

# Creating an empty list to store the result 
secret_word = []

# Creating a count variable which I will use later to determinate if the player wins
count = 1

for letter in word:
    secret_word.append('_')
secret_word[0] = word[0]

user_guess = input("Enter a letter: ")

# Here if the user guesses a letter
# We will place that letter on it's spot in our secret_word
while user_guess:
    if user_guess in word:
        print("Correct letter.")
        # adding 1 to count for every guessed letter
        count += 1
        # replacing the '_' with the letter
        for letter in range(len(word)):
            if user_guess == word[letter]:
                secret_word[letter] = word[letter]
        # here I am checking if the user has won
        if count == len(word):
            print("You Win!")
```

I gave you only a part of my program because I don't think that there's a need for the entire code.

My problem is in the count variable. As you can see I am adding + 1 to the variable every time when the user guesses a correct letter so when the count variable = len(word) my little program will know that the user had won.

Anyways when one single letters appears twice in the word like for example the word SEVEN haves the letter E two times my count variable still goes up by only 1 so  the user cant win in a case like this. I have absolutely no idea how to fix this and would be happy to receive some hints.

Thank you and please excuse my bad English and coding skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increment `count` whenever you replace an underscore with the correct the letter. That way, `count` will be equal to the number of letters correct in the word so far.

To be more clear, move `count += 1` to be in the `if` statement when you replace underscores with the actual letter.

One problem I see with this is you're giving the player the first letter and initializing `count` to 1. I don't know why you're doing this, but if the first letter occurs more than once, it won't be reflected in the word, and the player will still have to guess that letter anyways.

Comment: No OP is not. He incrementing it every time the use guesses a letter correctly. I am suggesting he increment it every time he replaces an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Move the count to where you are replacing the letter.

```
while user_guess:
    if user_guess in word:
        print("Correct letter.")
        # replacing the '_' with the letter
        for letter in range(len(word)):
            if user_guess == word[letter]:
                # adding 1 to count for every guessed letter
                count += 1
                secret_word[letter] = word[letter]
        # here I am checking if the user has won
        if count == len(word):
            print("You Win!")
```