# Can I replace the a certain place in a string with a letter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

After following some intro to python tutorials on youtube, I have been trying to make a hangman game. I want the output to show the letters being filled into blanks while they guess.

```
word = "cats"
display = "_ _ _ _ "
print(display)
```

Then the user would guess a. However, I don't think I can just use replace`because than the display would be "aaaa". I want to replace with numbers but it keeps giving me an error.

Comment: What error? What are you doing?

Comment: Have you considered using indexing?

Comment: strigns are immuteable. Use a list instead and index into it. Use `''.join( ["c","_","t","s"])` to get the string from the list

Comment: there are plenty of qustions about hangman games on SO and lots of tutorials.Google some- f.e. read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567911/python-hangman-game-python-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to store each letter of your word in an array, this way it is easier to search for certain letters using a 'for loop'.

```
word = ["c", "a", "t", "s"]
display = ["_", "_", "_", "_"]

guess = input("Enter a letter: ")

for x in range(0, len(word)):
  if word[x] == guess:
    display[x] = guess

print(display)
```